# I can not hear music after recording (Swift)

Tags: swift, avaudiorecorder, recording, headphones, avaudioengine

I make a karaoke app. If headphone doesn't plugin app works fine.(my voice and background music record together). it is successful. but I'm the same way with headphone Then I listen to the recording. I can not hear the background music.(its too much low).

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: https://github.com/genedelisa/AVFoundationRecorder